# php/mysql:what's the idea to active/inactive a code from being executed

Tags: mysql

i have a php code to show online users,my question is that how to make an option(yes,no) in the admin panel to control the appearance of enabling or disabling the code

just i want to know the idea for making something like that?what are the fields required?what are the queries to do that?

or an article discuss the process of activate or in activate some code from being executed according the state of selected option(y,n)

and a practical snippet for that.......

```
    session_start();
$session=session_id();
$time=time();
$time_check=$time-600; //SET TIME 10 Minute

$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="advphp_advphp"; // Mysql username
$password="112233"; // Mysql password
$db_name="advphp_download"; // Database name
$tbl_name="user_online"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect to server");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE session='$session'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count=="0"){
$sql1="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(session, time)VALUES('$session', '$time')";
$result1=mysql_query($sql1);
}
else {
"$sql2=UPDATE $tbl_name SET time='$time' WHERE session = '$session'";
$result2=mysql_query($sql2);
}

$sql3="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
$result3=mysql_query($sql3);

$count_user_online=mysql_num_rows($result3);

echo "المتواجدون الان : "; echo $count_user_online + 30;

// if over 10 minute, delete session
$sql4="DELETE FROM $tbl_name WHERE time<$time_check";
$result4=mysql_query($sql4);

mysql_close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can think of the list of online users as a module that you can configure from a back end.

Keep a XML file with the list of all the modules and their statuses (enabled/disabled) and allow the user to disable/enable the module from the back end by setting the right value for the module name in the XML file.

When you need to check the module you can either load the XML file and check the status or just keep a session variable with the statuses of the modules and decide according to that variable weather to show it or not.

Answer (score 0):

For each user add an extra field called privilege which stores if user has admin, special privilege

Write a php page like admin.php

if the logged in user has admin privilege then include the admin.php page in their homepage or else do not include the admin.php

admin,php will contain the additional features for an admin user

query

```
select username, status from tableName 
where loginName='$user' and password='$password';
```

then in code

```
if(row['status'] == 'admin')
{
include_once('admin.php');
}
```

Comment: thanks naveen for ur answer,but ididn't mean this,iwant to know the idea to make a field called active and how to put the value on it to allow the code from being enabled or disabled form viewing in the main page,just give me a snippet for that

Comment: add extra field Privilage and store an integer value in it like if the value is 0 then normal user else if it is 1 then superUser, later on you can give value 1 to intermediate user and 2 to superUser.